# How to echo Jenkins Workspace in Cygwin

Tags: windows, jenkins-pipeline, cygwin

I am trying to build a job from jenkins pipeline, my pipeline is calling one shell script which is on windows server, and this script is in cygwin terminal, question is how to use the Jenkins workspace in my shell script in cygwin, tried below commands are not working, can someone please advise. Thanks.

```
In jenkins Pipeline:
    
     sh "/home/test.sh $WORKSPACE"
In Cygwin:
#!/cygdrive/d/cygwin64/bin/bash --login

WORKSPACE=$1
echo "$WORKSPACE"

Out put from above command is 
D:Jenkinsworkspacey_test123_feature_test

but actual workspace is(multibranch pipeline) 
Running on win01 in D:\Jenkins\workspace\y_test123_feature_test
```

Not sure will cygwin take the different command to retrieve the workspace as you can see above output does not contains slashes in between words.

Comment: any log output ? Which shell is Jenkins using ?

Answer (score 0):

Workspace can be accessed using the enviornmental variable inside the pipeline.

```
In jenkins Pipeline:
// Get workspace
// This will give you the workspace of the agent that is available in the current stage
def Workspace=env.WORKSPACE
// Convert path with \\ for cygwin
Workspace.replace("\\", "\\\\");
println(Workspace)
sh "/home/test.sh ${Workspace}"
```

Comment: @Kumar does this works for you?Other possibility could be to add double slashes or convert it in cygwin path

Comment: @Kumar I have added conversion for path, so that you get correct output in cygwin.I have updated the answer, please can you  check.